# eBay API, how to get numerical Site ID from SiteCodeType

Tags: enums, global, ebay-api

In my app I want to give the user the opportunity to choose the site to explore.
What I do is showing a list of the existing sites (using a String array) and then get the SiteCodeType with the valueOf() method of the enum.

This value works with some APIs, but what I need is actually the specific ID of the site, and I can't find out how to get it. 
I hoped to get it somewhere using the SiteCodeType I already have.

I saw both GlobalID and SiteID but I don't understand how to work with them.

https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/merchandising/docs/CallRef/Enums/GlobalIdList.html
https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/merchandising/docs/Concepts/SiteIDToGlobalID.html

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This utility converts between **SiteCodeType** and eBay numerical **Site ID**.

https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/javasdk-jaxb/docs/LibRef/com/ebay/sdk/SiteIDUtil.html

Answer (score -1):

It's just a simple list with a couple dozen entries:
http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/types/SiteCodeType.html

All ya gotta do is create a simple array in your programming with a 1-to-1 mapping.

Comment: rickymarchiori's comment is the correct answer. If eBay is providing a utility, use that.